# Countifs returning values that is not tally with summation

Tags: excel-formula

im trying to countifs to check the number of rows that fit two criteria (matching the output table and column).[said tabulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGTtO.png)
formula: =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$163838,I$1,$F$2:$F$163838,$H2)

Ive had completely drag it fully. However, after summing up the total number of countifs results, it actually exceed the total number of rows, which doesnt make much sense.
[total sum of countifs=164012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQDLG.png)
[total no of rows=163838](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxk9n.png)

im hoping to resolve this issue by diagnosing the problem, maybe correct my formula.

Comment: Is there a circular reference somewhere? I see that mentioned in the bottom of your picture.

Comment: By circular reference, u mean inside the tabulation? Then no. Ive random checked multiple of them and they are referencing correctly. And, what do u mean mentioned at bottom of picture?

Comment: Just looking at rows 2 & 3 of your table if you drag the formula down you're going to count the both row 2 & 3 in the Col I2 & Col I3. I think you might be better served using a Pivot table for this?